# how to Reduce load time caused by multiple requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, load

I am developing a news aggregator website, in have added 24 publishers in it, all the publishers data is present in xml files, so i am calling them using ajax. But it is taking 30 sec to load the page.I have four sections in my webpage(for you, technology, politics,MOvies/tv) for each i have a external JS file. These files are requesting data. PLZ help me reduce the page load time, also suggest some  stratergies.

```
//technology JS file code sample  
  $.when($.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://feed.cnet.com/feed/topics/sci-tech'), $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://in.mashable.com/tech.xml')).then(function(r1, r2) {
        // console.log(r1[0]);
        // console.log(r2[0]);
        // cnet article
        $(r1[0]).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
            title = $(j).find('title').text();
            description = $(j).find('description').text();
            link = $(j).find('link').text();
            thumbnail = $(j).find('[url]').attr('url');
            newsname = "Cnet";
            logo = "http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/ne/gr/prtnr/CNET_Logo_150.gif";

            articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);

        });
        //Mashable articles
        $(r2[0]).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
            title = $(j).find('title').text();
            description = $(j).find('description').text();
            //pos3 = description.indexOf("</a>");
            // des = description.substring(pos3 + 2);
            // thumbnail = $(j).find('image').text();
            link = $(j).find('link').text();
            var pos2 = description.indexOf("width");
            var pos1 = description.indexOf("src=");
            thumbnail = description.substring(pos1 + 5, pos2 - 2);
            newsname = "Mashable India Tech";
            logo = "https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/255718/mashable-squarelogo-1430326903133.png";
            des = "";
            articlestech(i, title, des, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);

        });}) ;

//movies/tv shows code sample
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.cinemablend.com/rss/topic/reviews/movies",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(r1[0]).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
                    title = $(j).find('title').text();
                    description = $(j).find('description').text() + "...";
                    link = $(j).find('link').text();
                    //console.log(link);
                    thumbnail = $(j).find('enclosure').attr('url');
                    //console.log(thumbnail);
                    newsname = "Cinemablend";
                    logo = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.muckrack.com/groups/icons/cinemablend.jpeg";

                    articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);
                });
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.cinejosh.com/rss-feed/1/review.html",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
                    title = $(j).find('title').text();
                    //des = $(j).find('description').text();
                    link = $(j).find('link').text();
                    description = "";
                    thumbnail = $(j).find('[url]').attr('url');;
                    console.log(thumbnail);
                    newsname = "CineJosh";
                    logo = "https://www.cinejosh.com/gallereys/others/normal/cinejosh_logo_1902160805/cinejosh_logo_1902160805_01.jpg";

                    articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);
                });
            }
        });
```

Rest two JS files has same code structure.HOW TO REDUCE LOAD TIME.

Comment: Does the requests depend on each other?

Comment: they are seperate urls im requesting, its sequential, means only after whole data is requested from one url the other ajax request starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are waiting for all the six requests to return to start doing something with the responses. As I can see from the code snippet you provided the requests does not depend on each other, so you can do all of them separeted and as soon as the first request finishes the user will be able to see the result in the screen.

So, this:

```
$.when(
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://feed.cnet.com/feed/topics/sci-tech'),
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://in.mashable.com/tech.xml'),
  $.get('https://www.theverge.com/rss/tech/index.xml'),
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.buzzfeed.com/tech.xml'),
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.cnbc.com/id/19854910/device/rss/rss.html'),
  $.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.engadget.com/rss.xml'))
```

Needs to be something like this:

```
$.when($.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://feed.cnet.com/feed/topics/sci-tech')).then(function(r1) {
    $(r1[0]).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
        title = $(j).find('title').text();
        description = $(j).find('description').text();
        link = $(j).find('link').text();
        thumbnail = $(j).find('[url]').attr('url');
        newsname = "Cnet";
        logo = "http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/ne/gr/prtnr/CNET_Logo_150.gif";

        articlestech(i, title, description, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);
  });
})

$.when($.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://in.mashable.com/tech.xml')).then(function(r1) {
    $(r2[0]).find('item').each(function(i, j) {
        title = $(j).find('title').text();
        description = $(j).find('description').text();
        //pos3 = description.indexOf("</a>");
        // des = description.substring(pos3 + 2);
        // thumbnail = $(j).find('image').text();
        link = $(j).find('link').text();
        var pos2 = description.indexOf("width");
        var pos1 = description.indexOf("src=");
        thumbnail = description.substring(pos1 + 5, pos2 - 2);
        newsname = "Mashable India Tech";
        logo = "https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/255718/mashable-squarelogo-1430326903133.png";
        des = "";
        articlestech(i, title, des, link, thumbnail, newsname, logo);
  });
})
```

...

Comment: OK, I will check out

Comment: hi, i did try it and it did not make much difference, it is still taking a long time to load all the 4 JS scripts.